# "cl" not recognized as internal or external Command in visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-c++

so i'm following a tutorial tyope thing from udemy, and i've come to this point where no matter what i do, it will just show that it's not recognized. I did use developer command prompt for vs 2022, still didn't work, and i don't know what else i could do.

Comment: I'd uninstall VS and reinstall it.

Comment: Are you using "Visual Studio 2022" or "Visual Studio Code"? Two *totally* different products with extremely confusing names.

Comment: yes thank you Ted i reinstalled it and now it works

Comment: i'm using vs code